# TextBlock on top of ImageButton (Windows 8 XAML/C#)

Tags: c#, xaml, imagebutton, textblock

Can someone give me an example of how to style a button with XAML hat has three states (hover, normal, pressed). i want the whole area of the button to be covered with an image (one for each of the three different states) and i want text to be on top that also has three different colors for the different states. i have something like this already (without the color states on the textblock). the problem i'm having at this point is that the textblock is blocking the input events for the button undernearth (i also haven't implemented the color changes for the textblock....

current code:

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="SubjectItemTemplate">
    <Canvas Width="225" Height="225">
        <Button Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0"
                Command="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot, Path=DataContext.NavigateToUnitsPage}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding}">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid Background="{Binding LightThemeColor}" Width="205" Height="205">

                        <controls:ImageButton HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                              NormalStateImageSource="{Binding ImageUriNormal}"
                                              HoverStateImageSource="{Binding ImageUriHover}"
                                              PressedStateImageSource="{Binding ImageUriPressed}" Command="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot, Path=DataContext.NavigateToUnitsPage}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="18" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,168,0,0" />

                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>

        </Button>
    </Canvas>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: What do you mean `the textblock is blocking the input events`?

Comment: when i move the mouse over the imagebutton the image changes to the hover image. however, when i move the mouse over textblock (which is inside the image) the image does not change to the hover state. i also can't trigger the command by click on the image in the area of the textblock.

Comment: From your XAML, your `Textblock` is in-line with your `ImageButton`.

Comment: what do you mean by "in-line"?

Comment: Your `TextBlock` element is not located inside your `ImageButton`, but after it.

Comment: i meant inside as in physically... the textblock resides inside the rectangle that defines the image

Comment: anyway bob, you should list that as the answer so i can vote it as the answer. putting inside the imagebutton element solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that the `ImageButton` events are not being handled as expected with the `TextBlock` is because the `TextBlock` is located in-line with the `ImageButton` and not contained inside the `ImageButton`. To change this, the `TextBlock` has to be placed inside the `ImageButton`.

```
 <controls:ImageButton HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,0"
      NormalStateImageSource="{Binding ImageUriNormal}"
      HoverStateImageSource="{Binding ImageUriHover}"
      PressedStateImageSource="{Binding ImageUriPressed}" Command="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot, Path=DataContext.NavigateToUnitsPage}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" >
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="18" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,168,0,0" />
 </controls:ImageButton>
```